# How to get Openlayers cluster strategy work for large data?

Tags: openlayers-2, data, clustering

The map Layer has around 1500 points. I am able to display all the points in the map without any problem but adding the cluster strategy to the layer does not work. The Cluster strategy functions when I limit the number of points to 100.

Is there a way to cluster large amount of points in Openlayers?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly was the solution in the end? I'm at a similar issue and your solution could be of help for more people.

Answer (score 4):

i think there is a problem with your code. in normal case Openlayers clustering doesnt make problem with 1500 points . to understand clustering strategy, you can check out openflights.org clustering tutorial [here](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/10/21/customized-openlayers-cluster-strategies/).

beside this did you examine openlayers clustering example.

- Cluster Strategy Example, [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster.html)
- Extended clustering, [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html)

if you share your code, we may check out it..

i hope it helps you...

Comment: In addition, here's a pretty cool animated cluster strategy plugin. It extends OpenLayers.strategy.Cluster().  http://css.dzone.com/articles/animated-marker-cluster

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer..I figured out the problem and  it was not the number of points in the cluster.